# subtraction of iterators that give integer number

Tags: c++, iterator, operators

can someone tell me what happens under in this subtraction?
why did I get a number in the end? its build operator '-' or something else?

```
int main(){
    
    vector<int> v{5,3,8,3,9};
    auto p=remove(begin(v),end(v),3);
   
    cout<<p-begin(v);
   
    return 0;
}
```

output: 3

Comment: The vector iterator has an overloaded operator- which gives the distance between the iterators.

Comment: See also `std::distance(iter1, iter2)`, which returns `iter2-iter1` (note the reverse order). `std::distance` has the additional functionality of counting the distance if there's no `operator-`, which is of course a bit slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators for `std::vector` are [`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)s, and you can see in that link that subtracting one such iterator from another yields a `difference_type`.  For [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), this is defined as "a signed integer type (usually `std::ptrdiff_t`)", which sounds like what you wanted.

And yes, the magic occurs inside `operator-()` (for the iterator).